# Tabbed checkbox not working on mobile

Tags: css

I am trying to create a TABBED checkbox and everything works fine except on a mobile phone.  On a mobile phone, after I tap one of the tabs, it does nothing, but if I chnage the orientation, then it displays correctly.  Can anyone please help me.  In case it matters, I am testing on an old phone for compatibility, Android 4.4.2.

Here is a codepen with code:
http://codepen.io/lepew/pen/Ppqwez

```
    <div id="sign_Page">
    <br/>
    Please select "REGISTER" for new applicants, "LOGIN for current hello users and "FORGOT" if you need your password reset.
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="sign_Area">
        <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad1" class="tab1"/>
        <label for="rad1">REGISTER</label>
        <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad2" class="tab2" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="rad2">LOGIN</label>
        <input type="radio" name="tabGroup1" id="rad3" class="tab3"/>
        <label for="rad3">FORGOT</label>
        <div class="tab1"><!-- REGISTER -->
            <div class="sign_Case">
                SIGNUP
                <br/>
                <br/>
                SUMBIT
            </div><!-- end of #sign_Case -->
        </div><!-- end of TAB1 -->
        <div class="tab2"><!-- LOGIN -->
            <div class="sign_Case">
                LOGIN
                <br/>
                <br/>
                SUMBIT
            </div><!-- end of #sign_Case -->
        </div><!-- end of TAB1 -->
        <div class="tab3"><!-- FORGOT -->
            <div class="sign_Case">
                EMAIL
                <br/>
                <br/>
                SUMBIT
            </div><!-- end of #sign_Case -->
        </div><!-- end of TAB1 -->
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div><!-- end of #sign_Area -->
</div><!-- end of #sign_Page -->
```

Comment: I am using laptop with touch screen and it worked perfectly on both viewports and any window resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it works on everything except a mobile.  I checked can caniuse and everything is okay.

Comment: Which mobile browser do you use?

Comment: Samsung 3, version 4.4.2.  The part I do not understand is why does it display properly after I change the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Force the re-flow on the mobile as is induced by the orientation change.  These are script but you might do that...

```
someelement.style.display='none';
someelement.offsetHeight; // no need to store this anywhere, the reference is enough
someelement.style.display='';
```

Optionally a `timeout` of 0 triggers a reflow just like querying `offsetHeight` does:

```
sel.style.display = 'run-in'; 
setTimeout(function () { sel.style.display = 'block'; }, 0);
```

Comment: thank you Mark.  2 questions, is it really worth targeting such an old phone?  what do I replace someelement with?

Comment: `element = document.getElementById(id);` or something like that, pick an id on your page or even put one in specifically for that.  What you target is not a technical but a business/other decision - so it depends.